# general points in Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, grassmannian

what is the definition of general points or very general points  in Grassmannian Gr(k,n)?

because two points in grassmannian may not be connected by a line.

Comment: Usually, when one says general points of a variety $X$, one means the set of points in the complement of a proper closed subset. Very general means (and one says it only for varieites over an uncountable field), the points in the complement of a countable union of proper subvarieites.

Comment: @Mohan Should it be like this....two points are not general if there exists a line in Gr (2,4) which passes through them

Comment: I do not know what it means to say "two points are general". There are concepts of a bunch of points in general position (as opposed to a "general point"). Usually this comes up in projective spaces (and possibly for others embedded in a projective space). Is this what you are after?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01906.pdf  ..this is the paper I am looking at..they haven't defined it

Comment: Presumably they will specify as they proceed in the paper what general position means. I'm assuming it will be something like requiring that the no two points lie in a single Schubert cycle.

Comment: Most probably they mean the following. Two points in a variety $X$ is just a point in $S^2X$. So a general point (as I defined above) will correspond to two general points on $X$.

Answer (score 2):

As Mohan said in the comments, when someone says "For a set of $k$ points in $X$ in general position, *bla* is true", that means there is a proper closed subset $Z$ inside the symmetric product $X^{[k]}$ such that *bla* holds for all $k$-tuples outside $Z$. (For "very general" the story is similar, but now $Z$ might be a countable union of proper closed subsets.)

As Ted Shifrin said, what exactly the closed subset $Z$ is, *depends on the problem in question*.

In the case you are asking about, the author is talking in some places about two points in general position in $G(k,n)$, and he is assuming (by duality) that $n \geq 2k$. Looking at the proof of Theorem 3.8, we see that what this means here is that the two $k$-dimensional subspaces corresponding to the two points intersect only in the trivial subspace.

In the special case of $G(2,4)$, that is exactly the same as saying that the two points do not lie on a line, as you suggested in the comments.